# Substrings using recursive

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, substring

So I need to write a code using recursive method to get the substrings of the input, a proper example would be, if the input is:

> "abc" the output must be: a ab abc b bc c

and so on...
another example:

> input: "hello" output: h he hel hell hello e el ell ello l ll llo l lo
>   o

```
a=""
 if len(s)==1:
   return 
 for i in range(0,len(s)):
    for n in range(0,len(s)):   
       a+=s[i:n+1]+'\n'
```

this is a code that I wrote that does exactly what I need, only downside is it does not use any recursive, so if anyone could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your expected output, a summary of the program might be:

1. Write all the substrings belonging with the first char of the input string (`a ab abc`)
2. Write all the remaining substrings (`b bc c`)

In Python-ish pseudocode:

```
 def substrings(input):
      output = substrings_using_first_char(input)
      return output + substrings(input[1:])
```

`substrings_using_first_char()`, I will leave to you. It could be recursive, but there is an easy non-recursive implementation using a `for` loop. You could write the recursive version as an exercise.

There's a problem with the code above, however -- it *always* calls itself, so it will never return, and will overflow the stack. All recursive functions/methods require a stopping condition. So put one in:

```
 def substrings(input):
      if(input == ''):
          return []
      else:
          output = substrings_using_first_char(input)
          return output + substrings(input[1:])
```

This fits the universal format for recursive functions/methods:

```
recursiveMethod(input):
     if(input is simple case with easy answer):
         return answer for the simple case
     else:
         split input into a "small piece" and the "rest"
         return answer made by working with "small piece" and   
recursiveMethod(rest)
```

The whole thing can be tidied a bit, to remove the intermediate variable:

```
 def substrings(input):
      if(input == ''):
          return []
      else:
          return substrings_using_first_char(input) + substrings(input[1:])
```

I have made it return a list, rather than print to the screen, because this is generally a cleaner way to code, but you can adapt it to your needs.

---

Note that since Python doesn't optimize tail recursion, stack overflow is always a risk in Python. Recursion is useful (especially when working with trees) but when there's an obvious iterative solution, in Python it's usually better to use that.

Comment: That is great help indeed, but you see there's more to the code and a part of it that the input should not be empty, and if it was, it should raise `ValueError`

Comment: So, if input is empty, raise valueError. If input is length 1, return `[ input ]`, else recurse.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
public void test() {
    String abc = "abcdef";
    write(abc, 0, 1);
}

void write(String abc, int start, int end) {
    System.out.println(abc.substring(start, end));
    if (end == abc.length()) {
        if (start < abc.length() && start + 1 < abc.length()) {
            write(abc, start + 1, start + 2);
        }
    } else {
        write(abc, start, end + 1);
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
b
bc
bcd
bcde
bcdef
c
cd
cde
cdef
d
de
def
e
ef
f
```

Comment: what about the case of bcde, bcd, bc, b...etc?

Comment: @Edwardhk you are right, I have corrected the answer